# Unit testing file upload fails

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

I have an action that inserts a file in a database. It works fine. But the unit test fails when the insert is successful. The RedirectToRouteResult is null. This is the code for the action:

`[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult FileUpload(FileUploadViewModel model)
        {
            try
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    var uploadFile = new byte[model.File.InputStream.Length];
                    model.File.InputStream.Read(uploadFile, 0, uploadFile.Length);
                    //var file = new FilesUpload();
                    var fileExt = Path.GetExtension(model.File.FileName);
                    if (fileExt == ".txt" || fileExt == ".docx")
                    {
                        //file.FileName = model.File.FileName;
                        //file.FileSize = model.File.ContentLength;
                        //file.ContentType = fileExt;
                        //file.FileData = uploadFile;
                        //file.UploadedOn = DateTime.Now;
                        //var user = _userRepository.GetUserId(User.Identity.Name);
                        //file.UserId = user.UserId;
                        bool result = _userRepository.UploadFile(model, User.Identity.Name, fileExt, uploadFile);
                        //file.User = (from u in _context.Users where u.UserId == 29 select u).FirstOrDefault();
                        //_context.FilesUploads.Add(file);
                        //int result = _context.SaveChanges();
                        if (result)
                        {
                            return RedirectToAction("Index");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            ModelState.AddModelError("", "An error occured");
                            return View(model);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError("", "You can upload only files with extensions .txt and .docx");
                    }
                }
                return View(model);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw(ex);
            } 
        }`

And this is the code for the unit test:

```
    private SuperUserController _controller;
    private Mock<IUserRepository> _repositoryMock;
    private Mock<IIntrinsicObjects> _intrinsicMock;
    private Mock<ControllerContext> _contextMock;
    private string username = "test@abv.bg";
    private FileUploadViewModel _fileUpload;

    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        _fileUpload = new FileUploadViewModel();
        _repositoryMock = new Mock<IUserRepository>();
        _intrinsicMock = new Mock<IIntrinsicObjects>();
        _contextMock = new Mock<ControllerContext>();
        _contextMock.SetupGet(c => c.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name).Returns(username);
        _contextMock.SetupGet(c => c.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated).Returns(true);
        _controller = new SuperUserController(_repositoryMock.Object, _intrinsicMock.Object);
        _controller.ControllerContext = _contextMock.Object;
    }


[Test]
    public void FileUpload_ShouldRedirectToIndexOnSuccess()
    {
        string filePath = Path.GetFullPath(@"C:\Users\Test\Desktop\test.txt");
        var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open);
        var fileExt = Path.GetExtension(filePath);
        var fileToUpload = new Mock<HttpPostedFileBase>();
        fileToUpload.Setup(f => f.ContentLength).Returns(10);
        fileToUpload.Setup(f => f.FileName).Returns("test.txt");
        fileToUpload.Setup(f => f.ContentType).Returns(fileExt);
        fileToUpload.Setup(f => f.InputStream).Returns(fileStream);
        //var model = new FileUploadViewModel();
        _fileUpload.File = fileToUpload.Object;
        var fileData = new byte[fileToUpload.Object.InputStream.Length];
        _repositoryMock.Setup(m => m.UploadFile(_fileUpload, _controller.ControllerContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name, fileToUpload.Object.ContentType, fileData)).Returns(true);
        var result = _controller.FileUpload(_fileUpload) as RedirectToRouteResult;
        Assert.IsNotNull(result);
    }
```

The problem is that UploadFile always returns false.

I will be very grateful if somebody helps me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your controller action creates a new array with the file data:

```
var uploadFile = new byte[model.File.InputStream.Length];
```

That is never going to match the `fileData` argument set on the `UploadFile` of your `_repositoryMock`:

```
_repositoryMock.Setup(m => m.UploadFile(_fileUpload, _controller.ControllerContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name, fileToUpload.Object.ContentType, fileData)).Returns(true);
```

By default the array will match by reference, not if the contents are the same. As the controller creates a new instance, `uploadFile` is a different reference than `fileData`.

You want to setup moq so when the expected data array is submitted your UploadFile function returns true. For that you can use an custom matcher that matches all elements in an enumerable:

```
public T[] MatchCollection<T>(T[] expectation)
{
    //This checks all elements in input are find in destination, regardless of order or duplicates
    return Match.Create<T[]>(inputCollection => (expectation.All((i) => inputCollection.Contains(i))));

    //This will check the arrays are exactly the same
    return Match.Create<T[]>(inputCollection =>  StructuralComparisons.StructuralEqualityComparer.Equals(inputCollection, expectation) );
}
```

And setup your mock using that matcher for the data array:

```
_repositoryMock.Setup(m => m.UploadFile(_fileUpload, _controller.ControllerContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name, fileToUpload.Object.ContentType, MatchCollection(fileData))).Returns(true);
```

Hope it helps!

**EDIT**

---

I have tried with the following test based on your code that passes a valid array data to the mock setup and doesn´t need to actually read a file in the unit test:

```
public void FileUpload_ShouldRedirectToIndexOnSuccess()
{
    var fileData = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("This is a test");
    var fileStream = new MemoryStream(fileData);

    var fileToUpload = new Mock<HttpPostedFileBase>();
    fileToUpload.Setup(f => f.ContentLength).Returns((int)fileStream.Length);
    fileToUpload.Setup(f => f.FileName).Returns("test.txt");
    fileToUpload.Setup(f => f.ContentType).Returns("txt");
    fileToUpload.Setup(f => f.InputStream).Returns(fileStream);
    _fileUpload.File = fileToUpload.Object;            

    _repositoryMock
        .Setup(m => m.UploadFile(_fileUpload, username, ".txt", MatchCollection(fileData)))
        .Returns(true);

    var result = _controller.FileUpload(_fileUpload) as RedirectToRouteResult;
    Assert.IsNotNull(result);
}
```

Comment: Could you tell me where I have to put this matcher?

Comment: It gives me an error that "cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<byte>' to 'byte[]'"

Comment: Sorry, the return type of the matcher should be the same as the parameter input, so you will need a matcher for `T[]` and not `IEnumerable<T>`. I have updated the answer.

Comment: It still gives false. Any idea why is that?

Comment: I found that the array created in the test contains only zeros while the one in the controller contains values different from zero. And maybe this is the reason it doesn't work.

Comment: right, in your test you are doing `var fileData = new byte[fileToUpload.Object.InputStream.Length];` which is just initializing an byte array with zeros. However the matcher is now checking the array data!

Comment: Could you help with a solution as I tried so many things but it didn't work? Thank you in advance :)

Comment: @YordankaToteva, just updated the answer with a test I have debugged. You may want to have a look, as you don´t need to keep a separated text file for your test :)

Answer (score 0):

This is the final version of the test:

```
[Test]
    public void FileUpload_ShouldRedirectToIndexOnSuccess()
    {
        string filePath = Path.GetFullPath(@"C:\Users\Yordanka\Desktop\test.txt");
        var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open);
        var fileExt = Path.GetExtension(filePath);
        var testarray = new byte[414];
        var fileToUpload = new Mock<HttpPostedFileBase>();
        fileToUpload.Setup(f => f.ContentLength).Returns(414);
        fileToUpload.Setup(f => f.FileName).Returns("test.txt");
        fileToUpload.Setup(f => f.ContentType).Returns(fileExt);
        fileToUpload.Setup(f => f.InputStream).Returns(fileStream);
        fileToUpload.Setup(f => f.InputStream.Length).Returns(testarray.Length);
        _fileUpload.File = fileToUpload.Object;
        var fileData = new byte[414];
        _fileUpload.File.InputStream.Read(fileData, 0, fileData.Length);
        _repositoryMock.Setup(
            m =>
                m.UploadFile(_fileUpload, _controller.ControllerContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name,
                    fileToUpload.Object.ContentType, MatchCollection(fileData))).Returns(true);
        var result = _controller.FileUpload(_fileUpload) as RedirectToRouteResult;
        Assert.IsNotNull(result);
        Assert.AreEqual("Index", result.RouteValues["Action"]);
        Assert.AreEqual("SuperUser", result.RouteValues["Controller"]);

    }
```

Once again, thank you Daniel J.G.!!!